# Short hand for jquery selector ":checked" applied on a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of jquery radio buttons :

```
<input type="radio" class="editorInput" name="radioEditor" value="1" id="radio_1">
<input type="radio" class="editorInput" name="radioEditor" value="2" id="radio_2">
<input type="radio" class="editorInput" name="radioEditor" value="3" id="radio_3">
<input type="radio" class="editorInput" name="radioEditor" value="4" id="radio_4">
```

I need to find the one that is checked, and get its value (or text).

For value I know I can do :

```
var val = $(".editorInput:checked").val();
```

But in some other cases, in my script I have an already build list containing these controls, for example selected by

```
var list = $(".editorInput");
```

The only way I know to get the checked one in this list requires to write an each iterator :

```
$(list).each(function ()
{
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        val = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

My question is : is there a shorter jquery syntax to get the "checked" radio button from a list of controls (like above)  containing several controls, in a single line ?

Thank you

Comment: You can [filter jQuery Objects](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) so try something like `.filter(':checked')`

Comment: @cloned $(list).filter(':checked') is the solution, thanks for sharing it. You can post it as an answer if you wish, or I'll do !

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the purpose is to work on the already existing list of items, built with a (supposed unknown) selector combination done previouly, to just extract the ":checked" items among them. "cloned" gave the solution :).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan consider that when I need to apply the ":checked" filter I only have the "list" object already built, as in the example, and not the ability to execute a complete selector because i'm in another method that the one doing the selection of the control list. It's for a complicated script (>1000 lines of JS). ".filter()" does exactly what I need. Thank you anyway !

Comment: Ah, I see now. Sorry, I missed that part of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify jQuery objects, for example one way to do it is `[filter() Method][1]`

Another honorably mentions should go to [find() Method](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector)

`$list.filter(':checked')` filters out checked elements.

`$ulList.find('li')` finds all `<li>` elements inside the list.